# SOLR: after duplicating one core, it doesn't rebuild the data

Tags: solr

I duplicate da working core
given a new name etc..

and in my SOLR admin panel everything looks good

but when i try to execute the data-config.xml
the rebuild fails providing zero fetch...

what could cause the problem>

Comment: What does "logs" say?

Answer (score 0):

oh usual mistake:

chmod folders: `index`, `spellchecker`, `tlog`!